# Upload file programmatically

Tags: uploads

I am trying to programmatically add multiple images to media library, I uploaded the images to `wp-content/uploads/dits`.

I am working with this code but this code is not working, can you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

  global $wp_filesystem;
  WP_Filesystem();

  $content_directory = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . 'uploads/';
  $wp_filesystem->mkdir( $content_directory . 'dits' );
  $target_dir_location = $content_directory . 'dits/';

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $_SESSION['message'] = $message;

   $name_file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];

   if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $target_dir_location.$name_file ) ) {
      echo "File was successfully uploaded";
   } else {
      echo "The file was not uploaded";
   }

   }

<form action="<?php echo site_url('370-2/?step=contact'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="120" placeholder="Describe the project" required="required"> <?php  echo $prj_description; ?> </textarea>
                <div class="container drag_con">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                          <!--<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="dropzone">-->
                          <input type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc,audio/*,.docx,video/*,.ppt,.pptx,.txt,.pdf" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" multiple>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <div class="next-button-box text-center mt-5">
                         <button  type="submit" name="submit" class="primary-button" id="next">NEXT</button>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: @Rup thx for reply, ok i wil try

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/) or [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/)?

Comment: Error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Filesystem' not found in

Comment: @kero plz modify my question And tell me what is the correct code

Comment: help me its very urgent for me

Comment: I thought WP_Filesystem was included everywhere in the admin site? Where are you running this code? Is it in the front end or the admin site? Is it in an action handler? If it's in the front end you probably do need to include some of the admin site files to get access to these functions and classes.

Comment: i m using this code in plugin for front end

Comment: OK, then you need to `require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php';` and then just call `WP_Filesystem()` (you were right - it's not a class as I'd thought) to set up the $wp_filesystem global.

Comment: @Rup thx,, but Sir, I tried it too, but it is not working when I am submitting, then my file is not uploading in the upload folder

Comment: I've never done this myself sorry. I guess you need to print_r out $_FILES or add other trace to debug what's going on.

Comment: I also followed but still nothing happened >> https://makitweb.com/programmatically-file-upload-from-custom-plugin-in-wordpress/